# how to add multiple contacts in android development?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I'm trying to develop a "Add contact" android app.I need to add multiple contact from my android application. The scenario is I have a "Name","Number" formatted csv file. This file has more than records. so need to read the file & add the contact.

Thanks in advance.